# How to properly export module / publish package ("Cannot find module")

Tags: javascript, typescript, backstage

I tried to do a basic plugin for Backstage (backstage.io by Spotify) following tutorial from their website (https://backstage.io/docs/plugins/create-a-plugin). It works when running inside the app created with `@backstage/create-app`.

I published the package to npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/backstage-dev-friends-days
but when I install it using `yarn add` in another Backstage instance app I'm getting `Cannot find module 'backstage-dev-friends-days' or its corresponding type declarations` in the line with `import { DevFriendsDayCard } from 'backstage-dev-friends-days';`

Before running `yarn publish` I run `tsc`, but I feel some lack of knowledge about TS and JS and might put something wrong in tsconfig.json or package.json.

The plugin code is here: https://github.com/piatkiewicz/backstage-plugins/tree/main/dev-friends-days

Comment: You have `"types": "dist/index.d.ts"` in your *package.json* but [your published files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/backstage-dev-friends-days?activeTab=code) don't include that.

Comment: I did some changes and getting `No inputs were found in config file ' ... tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["*/src","*/dev"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["dist-types"]'` when running tsc

Comment: I changed `include` paths and tsc works now, but getting first error again

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally works, can't explain it in details, but those are working files:

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "@backstage/cli/config/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "src",
    "dev"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist-types",
    "rootDir": "."
  }
}
```

package.json

```json
//...
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "private": false,
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public",
    "main": "dist/index.esm.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts"
  },
//...
```

Did just run "tsc" from the main catalog / with tsconfig and then publish.